# I try to get the head directory in git but I'm not succeeding in GIT

Tags: git

I used this command cat .git\HEAD for getting the head directory
but that's what I got cat: .git/HEAD: Not a directory

Comment: `HEAD` is indeed a file. It stores the reference of what's currently checked out. (Often a branch name, but it can just be a commit hash.)

Comment: Note that `HEAD` may not be in `.git` after all: for instance, if you're in an added work-tree, it will be somewhere else. Use `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the hash ID, or other flavors of rev-parse for other similar purposes. Use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to get the stored branch name (or an error if `HEAD` is detached).